How to add OptionSets in FakeXrmEasy context
I am creating unit tests with FakeXrmEasy and some of the tested functionality is accessing optionset data with following method:
private string GetOptionSetText(ICommonContext ctx, string entityName, string fieldName, int optionSetValue)
{
    RetrieveAttributeRequest attReq = new RetrieveAttributeRequest();
    attReq.EntityLogicalName = entityName;
    attReq.LogicalName = fieldName;
    attReq.RetrieveAsIfPublished = true;
    var attResponse = (RetrieveAttributeResponse)ctx.OrganizationService.Execute(attReq);
    var attMetadata = (EnumAttributeMetadata)attResponse.AttributeMetadata;
    return attMetadata.OptionSet.Options.Where(x => x.Value == optionSetValue).FirstOrDefault().Label.LocalizedLabels[0].Label;
}

Now, to make this possible I need to add the particular optionset to the metadata of the relevant entity in the FakeXrmEasy-Context.
I have tried the following as an example to test it:
private static void InitializeSingleOptionSet(XrmFakedContext context)
{
    // Create the OptionSet options
    var options = new List<OptionMetadata>
    {
        new OptionMetadata(new Label("Active", 1033), 1),
        new OptionMetadata(new Label("Inactive", 1033), 2)
    };

    // Create the OptionSetMetadata for the "statuscode" attribute
    var optionSetMetadata = new OptionSetMetadata(new OptionMetadataCollection(options));

    // Create the PicklistAttributeMetadata for "statuscode"
    var picklistAttribute = new PicklistAttributeMetadata
    {
        LogicalName = "statuscode",
        OptionSet = optionSetMetadata
    };

    // Create the AttributeMetadataCollection with a single attribute
    var attributes = new AttributeMetadataCollection
    {
        picklistAttribute
    };

    // Create EntityMetadata for the "salesorder" entity
    var entityMetadata = new EntityMetadata
    {
        LogicalName = "salesorder"
    };

    // Set the Attributes collection for the entity metadata
    entityMetadata.SetAttributeMetadataCollection(attributes);

    // Initialize metadata in the FakeXrmEasy context
    context.InitializeMetadata(entityMetadata);
}

I have tried so many versions but mostly I get errors like this:

Am I completely wrong or do I miss something? I have tried so many examples but I am not able to add the optionset to the context.
Does anybody have an idea how to achieve that in FakeXrmEasy?
Any help is highly appreciated!
